# Trouble incrementing ID without using autoincrement Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I am new to andorid studio and building a sports stats app. I am using an SQLite database to store players, squads and stats. **15 players** can be added to a **squad** in the **'squad' table**, after which i wish to increment the **'squad_id'** by 1. This is the schema for the 'squad' table

```
                squad_table_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                squad_id INTEGER
                squad_name TEXT
                player_name TEXT
                player_no INTEGER
```

'squad_id' is not the PK and I cannot use autoincrement. I have used a query to display the squads with a DISTINCT id which will be clicked to display all players in the squad. There is a button that allows the user to type in 15 names and the method below is what is added to the database.

**The squad_increment is reset every time the activity is opened, so all the players are being added to the database with the same 'squad_id'. HOW can I ensure the 'squad_id' is incremented after every 15 players are added?**

```
public class AddNewSquad extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, player6, player7, player8, player9,
    player10, player11, player12,player13, player14, player15;
    private Button addPlayerButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_squad_setup);

        player1 = findViewById(R.id.player1input);
        player2 = findViewById(R.id.player2input);
        player3 = findViewById(R.id.player3input);
        player4 = findViewById(R.id.player4input);
        player5 = findViewById(R.id.player5input);
        player6 = findViewById(R.id.player6input);
        player7 = findViewById(R.id.player7input);
        player8 = findViewById(R.id.player8input);
        player9 = findViewById(R.id.player9input);
        player10 = findViewById(R.id.player10input);
        player11 = findViewById(R.id.player11input);
        player12 = findViewById(R.id.player12input);
        player13 = findViewById(R.id.player13input);
        player14 = findViewById(R.id.player14input);
        player15 = findViewById(R.id.player15input);


        addPlayers();
    }

    public void addPlayers(){
        addPlayerButton = findViewById(R.id.addPlayersButton);
        addPlayerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int squad_increment = 0;
                MyDatabaseHelper myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(AddNewSquad.this);
              
                myDB.addtoSquad(String.valueOf(squad_increment), "My First Squad", player1.getText().toString().trim(), String.valueOf(1));
                myDB.addtoSquad(String.valueOf(squad_increment), "My First Squad", player2.getText().toString().trim(), String.valueOf(2));
                myDB.addtoSquad(String.valueOf(squad_increment), "My First Squad", player3.getText().toString().trim(), String.valueOf(3));
                myDB.addtoSquad(String.valueOf(squad_increment), "My First Squad", player4.getText().toString().trim(), String.valueOf(4));
                myDB.addtoSquad(String.valueOf(squad_increment), "My First Squad", player5.getText().toString().trim(), String.valueOf(5));
                myDB.addtoSquad(String.valueOf(squad_increment), "My First Squad", player6.getText().toString().trim(), String.valueOf(6));
                myDB.addtoSquad(String.valueOf(squad_increment), "My First Squad", player7.getText().toString().trim(), String.valueOf(7));
                myDB.addtoSquad(String.valueOf(squad_increment), "My First Squad", player8.getText().toString().trim(), String.valueOf(8));
                myDB.addtoSquad(String.valueOf(squad_increment), "My First Squad", player9.getText().toString().trim(), String.valueOf(9));
                myDB.addtoSquad(String.valueOf(squad_increment), "My First Squad", player10.getText().toString().trim(), String.valueOf(10));
                myDB.addtoSquad(String.valueOf(squad_increment), "My First Squad", player11.getText().toString().trim(), String.valueOf(11));
                myDB.addtoSquad(String.valueOf(squad_increment), "My First Squad", player12.getText().toString().trim(), String.valueOf(12));
                myDB.addtoSquad(String.valueOf(squad_increment), "My First Squad", player13.getText().toString().trim(), String.valueOf(13));
                myDB.addtoSquad(String.valueOf(squad_increment), "My First Squad", player14.getText().toString().trim(), String.valueOf(14));
                myDB.addtoSquad(String.valueOf(squad_increment), "My First Squad", player15.getText().toString().trim(), String.valueOf(15));
                Intent intent = new Intent(AddNewSquad.this, SavedSquads.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have tried moving the 'squad_increment' variable around, but again I am finding every time I open the activity the variable is being reset to 0. My database is being updated successfully, so my issue lies here.

Cheers

Comment: Take care of java namaning conventions. Variable names should be camelCase not snake_case

Comment: Is it local the db in the android app or is it a remote id on a server?

Comment: @juan it is local

Comment: It is ony one device updating the DB, so you can check the max id before inserting a new record. The new record would be inserted taking that value and adding one to it. If the value changes every 15 records, get a count of the records with the max id, and upate accordingly.

Comment: You getResources().getIdentifier()

Comment: @Juan I implemented a getMaxID method and it worked, thanks for your help